# Using Bootstrap.TimerPicker with MVC not picking the right time

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I tried to use this component but it is not showing the right time, when I remove the javascript "timepicker" it shows a normal input with the right datetime, but after using the component it shows wrong times. Why?

> It seems to be picking up the date part **20/05**. Should I use another
>   format? Such as **TimeSpan** instead of DateTime?

**MVC View**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartTime, new {@class = "form-control timepicker"})
```

**Javacript**

```
 $('.timepicker').timepicker({autoclose: true,minuteStep: 15,showSeconds: false,showMeridian: false});
```

**Screen**

[image]

**View**

As you can see below the times are different, those values are the Model of the View.

[image]

http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: Have you inspected the HTTP request to see if there are differences in the `DateTime` sent to the server?

Comment: Yes. but I found the problem I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution:**

The Jquery Plugin Bootstrap.Timepicker must be used using the data type `TimeSpan`.

After changing the datatype from `DateTime` to `TimeSpan` it worked perfectly.

```
public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
```

> Note: When you use a DateTime format it takes the first part of the date, in my example
>   **20/05** was converted to **20:05**.

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the problem, `TimeSpan` is a type to represent a period of time like `2 hours`, `30 days`, or `1.67 years`. But from your model, `StartTime` represents a `DateTime`, an actual date & time like `2015-09-10 11:23:45`.

Comment: @rexcfnghk when I save it I concat my other property Date + StartTime.  In this case, do you think it will work?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but this problem also occurs when using the Bootstrap DateTimePicker (v4 at the moment).

Using your example, the following would also produce **20:05**;

```
$(function () {
    var timeFormat = "HH:mm";

    $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: timeFormat
    });
});
```

However, changing `"HH:mm"` to `" HH:mm"` (mind the whitespace) got me the desired result;

```
$(function () {
    var timeFormat = " HH:mm";

    $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: timeFormat
    });
});
```

This produces **5:10** or **3:17** as desired.

I think it's a bug, as it should work without the whitespace. This is a workaround until the bug is fixed.